# how to save previous rectangles after update()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

[image: a1]
[image: a2]

user can draw rectangles by this application by giving clicking twice on grey picture. But this application dont saves last rectangles, instead of saving its drawing(updateing) a new rectangle by 2 next points. how i can solve this problem? how can i save previouse rectangles too?

```
class myQLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(myQLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.trafficlines = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        #print mode
        self.x = QMouseEvent.x()
        self.y = QMouseEvent.y()
        if self.x != 0 and self.y != 0:
            self.trafficlines.append(copy.deepcopy([self.x,self.y]))
        print "______"
        print self.x
        print self.y
        print "("+str(mode)+")"
        print "______"

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        super(myQLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        if mode == 0:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red,3))
        elif mode == 1:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue,3))
        elif mode == 2:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green,3))
        elif mode == 3:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.magenta,3))
        if len(self.trafficlines)%2==1 and len(self.trafficlines)>0:
            painter.drawPoint(self.trafficlines[-1][0],self.trafficlines[-1][1])
        if len(self.trafficlines)%2==0 and len(self.trafficlines)>0 and mode!=0:
            painter.drawLine( self.trafficlines[-2][0],self.trafficlines[-2][1],self.trafficlines[-1][0],self.trafficlines[-1][1] )
        if len(self.trafficlines)%2==0 and len(self.trafficlines)>0 and mode==0:
            x1=self.trafficlines[-2][0]
            y1=self.trafficlines[-2][1]
            x2=self.trafficlines[-1][0]
            y2=self.trafficlines[-1][1]
            painter.drawLine( x1,y1,x1,y2)
            painter.drawLine( x1,y2,x2,y2)
            painter.drawLine( x2,y2,x2,y1)
            painter.drawLine( x2,y1,x1,y1)



        self.update()
```

This is all the code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys, os
import copy

mode = 5

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.main_image_name="C:\Python27\project\main_image.png"

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        File_name = QLabel('Setup file name')
        File_name_edit = QLineEdit()
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        #QMainWindow.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.resize(640, 360)
        #self.setFixedSize(640, 360)
        self.center()
        self.main_image = myQLabel(self)
        self.main_image.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.main_image_name))
        btn = QPushButton("Make setup file")
        btn.setToolTip('Press <b>Detect</b> button for detecting objects by your settings')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        btn_browse = QPushButton("Browse")
        btn_browse.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        btn_set = QPushButton("Set name")
        #fullscreen
        #self.main_image.setScaledContents(True)
        #just centered
        self.main_image.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)



        #Layout
        box_File_name = QHBoxLayout()
        box_File_name.addWidget(File_name)
        box_File_name.addWidget(File_name_edit)
        box_File_name.addWidget(btn_set)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addLayout(box_File_name, 1, 0)
        #grid.addWidget(File_name_edit, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.main_image, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(btn_browse, 3 , 0)
        grid.addWidget(btn, 4, 0)

        box_number = QVBoxLayout()
        number_group=QButtonGroup() # Number group
        r0=QRadioButton("Traffic Lights")
        number_group.addButton(r0)
        r1=QRadioButton("Direction")
        number_group.addButton(r1)
        r2=QRadioButton("Traffic Lines H")
        number_group.addButton(r2)
        r3=QRadioButton("Traffic Lines V")
        number_group.addButton(r3)
        box_number.addWidget(r0)
        box_number.addWidget(r1)
        box_number.addWidget(r2)
        box_number.addWidget(r3)

        r0.toggled.connect(self.radio0_clicked)
        r1.toggled.connect(self.radio1_clicked)
        r2.toggled.connect(self.radio2_clicked)
        r3.toggled.connect(self.radio3_clicked)

        box_road_sign = QHBoxLayout()
        road_sign_label = QLabel('Road signs', self)
        road_sign = QComboBox()
        road_sign.addItem("None")
        road_sign.addItem("ex1")
        road_sign.addItem("ex2")
        road_sign.addItem("ex3")
        road_sign.addItem("ex4")
        road_sign.addItem("ex5")
        box_road_sign.addWidget(road_sign_label)
        box_road_sign.addWidget(road_sign)
        grid.addLayout(box_road_sign, 1, 1)
        grid.addLayout(box_number, 2, 1)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.show()
    def browse(self):
        w = QWidget()
        w.resize(320, 240)
        w.setWindowTitle("Select Picture")
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(w, 'Open File', '/')
        self.main_image_name = filename
        self.main_image.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.main_image_name))

    def center(self):

        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


    def radio0_clicked(self, enabled):
        if enabled:
            print("0")
            global mode
            mode=0

    def radio1_clicked(self, enabled):
        if enabled:
            print("1")
            global mode
            mode=1

    def radio2_clicked(self, enabled):
        if enabled:
            print("2")
            global mode
            mode=2

    def radio3_clicked(self, enabled):
        if enabled:
            print("3")
            global mode
            mode=3


class myQLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(myQLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.trafficlines = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        #print mode
        self.x = QMouseEvent.x()
        self.y = QMouseEvent.y()
        if self.x != 0 and self.y != 0:
            self.trafficlines.append(copy.deepcopy([self.x,self.y]))
        print "______"
        print self.x
        print self.y
        print "("+str(mode)+")"
        print "______"

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        super(myQLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        if mode == 0:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red,3))
        elif mode == 1:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue,3))
        elif mode == 2:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green,3))
        elif mode == 3:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.magenta,3))
        if len(self.trafficlines)%2==1 and len(self.trafficlines)>0:
            painter.drawPoint(self.trafficlines[-1][0],self.trafficlines[-1][1])
        if len(self.trafficlines)%2==0 and len(self.trafficlines)>0 and mode!=0:
            painter.drawLine( self.trafficlines[-2][0],self.trafficlines[-2][1],self.trafficlines[-1][0],self.trafficlines[-1][1] )
        if len(self.trafficlines)%2==0 and len(self.trafficlines)>0 and mode==0:
            x1=self.trafficlines[-2][0]
            y1=self.trafficlines[-2][1]
            x2=self.trafficlines[-1][0]
            y2=self.trafficlines[-1][1]
            painter.drawLine( x1,y1,x1,y2)
            painter.drawLine( x1,y2,x2,y2)
            painter.drawLine( x2,y2,x2,y1)
            painter.drawLine( x2,y1,x1,y1)



        self.update()

class menubarex(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(menubarex, self).__init__(parent)
        self.form_widget = Example(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        #self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        #self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.setWindowTitle('mi ban')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:\Python27\project\icon.png'))

    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
            QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #ex = Example()
    menubar = menubarex()
    menubar.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: this is just for setting color

Comment: mode changes only by radio buttons

Comment: right . but in any case, this class refreshes a new line or rectangle, and dont saves the last ones

Comment: only mode=0 case draws red rectangle by 2 points, other 3 modes draws lines by 2 points by different colors

Comment: i wrote whole the code below

Comment: eyllanesc, thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paintEvent()` redraws the entire widget, so it does not save memory from the previous drawing, so the rectangles or previous lines are not saved. The solution is to store those states and redraw everything again, for this we can store the mode and points in `trafficlines` as shown below:

```
class myQLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(myQLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.trafficlines = []
        self.mode = 0
        self.start_point = QPoint()

    def setMode(self, mode):
        self.mode = mode

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.start_point.isNull():
            self.start_point = event.pos()
        else:
            self.trafficlines.append((self.mode,[self.start_point, event.pos()]))
            self.start_point = QPoint()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(myQLabel, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)

        colors = [Qt.red, Qt.blue, Qt.green, Qt.magenta]

        for mode, points in self.trafficlines:
            painter.setPen(QPen(colors[mode],3))
            if mode != 0:
                painter.drawLine(*points)
            else:
                rect = QRect(*points)
                painter.drawRect(rect)

        if not self.start_point.isNull():
            painter.setPen(QPen(colors[self.mode],3))
            painter.drawPoint(self.start_point)
```

---

**Note:** do not use global variables, they are difficult to debug, in addition to unnecessary many times.

Also I take the liberty to improve your code by making it more readable with fewer lines. The complete code is in the following part:

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.main_image_name="C:\Python27\project\main_image.png"
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        File_name = QLabel('Setup file name')
        File_name_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.resize(640, 360)
        self.center()
        self.main_image = myQLabel(self)
        self.main_image.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.main_image_name))
        btn = QPushButton("Make setup file")
        btn.setToolTip('Press <b>Detect</b> button for detecting objects by your settings')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        btn_browse = QPushButton("Browse")
        btn_browse.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        btn_set = QPushButton("Set name")
        self.main_image.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        #Layout
        box_File_name = QHBoxLayout()
        box_File_name.addWidget(File_name)
        box_File_name.addWidget(File_name_edit)
        box_File_name.addWidget(btn_set)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addLayout(box_File_name, 1, 0)
        #grid.addWidget(File_name_edit, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.main_image, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(btn_browse, 3 , 0)
        grid.addWidget(btn, 4, 0)

        box_number = QVBoxLayout()
        number_group = QButtonGroup(self) # Number group

        for i, text in enumerate(["Traffic Lights", "Direction", "Traffic Lines H", "Traffic Lines V"]):
            rb = QRadioButton(text)
            box_number.addWidget(rb)
            number_group.addButton(rb, i)
        number_group.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.main_image.setMode)
        number_group.button(0).setChecked(True)

        box_road_sign = QHBoxLayout()
        road_sign_label = QLabel('Road signs', self)
        road_sign = QComboBox()
        road_sign.addItems(["None", "ex1", "ex2","ex3", "ex4", "ex5"])
        box_road_sign.addWidget(road_sign_label)
        box_road_sign.addWidget(road_sign)
        grid.addLayout(box_road_sign, 1, 1)
        grid.addLayout(box_number, 2, 1)

    def browse(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '/')
        self.main_image_name = filename
        self.main_image.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.main_image_name))

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

class myQLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(myQLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.trafficlines = []
        self.mode = 0
        self.start_point = QPoint()

    def setMode(self, mode):
        self.mode = mode

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.start_point.isNull():
            self.start_point = event.pos()
        else:
            self.trafficlines.append((self.mode,[self.start_point, event.pos()]))
            self.start_point = QPoint()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(myQLabel, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)

        colors = [Qt.red, Qt.blue, Qt.green, Qt.magenta]

        for mode, points in self.trafficlines:
            painter.setPen(QPen(colors[mode],3))
            if mode != 0:
                painter.drawLine(*points)
            else:
                rect = QRect(*points)
                painter.drawRect(rect)

        if not self.start_point.isNull():
            painter.setPen(QPen(colors[self.mode],3))
            painter.drawPoint(self.start_point)


class menubarex(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(menubarex, self).__init__(parent)
        self.form_widget = Example(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.setWindowTitle('mi ban')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:\Python27\project\icon.png'))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
            QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #ex = Example()
    menubar = menubarex()
    menubar.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```